# Get-GPResultantSetOfPolicy throws "...the report cant be generated for user..."

Tags: powershell, group-policy

I am trying to generate the RSOP from serveral of our servers. All I need are the Computer not the User results.

This is the PowerShell code I am using:

```
$computers = (Get-ADComputer -Filter ... -SearchBase ...).Name 

foreach  ($computer in $computers)
{
    Get-GPResultantSetOfPolicy -Computer $computer -ReportType xml -Path ...
}
```

This is going to throw an exception on some of the servers which is basically saying I have never logged in and therefor no Profile exists.

> Get-GPResultantSetOfPolicy : The Resultant Set of Policy (RSoP) report
>   cannot be generated for user MyUser on the MyComputer computer because
>   there is no RSoP logging data  for that user on that computer. This
>   could be because the user has never logged onto that computer.
>   Parameter name: User At line:1 char:1
>   + Get-GPResultantSetOfPolicy -computer MyComputer -ReportType xml -path d:\ ...
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (Microsoft.Group...OfPolicyCommand:GetGPResultantSetOfPolicyCommand)
>   [Get-GPResultantSetOfPolicy], ArgumentException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NoLoggingData,Microsoft.GroupPolicy.Commands.GetGPResultantSetOfPolicyCommand

The default behaviour of this cmdlet is to use the default user, meaning the user executing the cmdlet.

Of course there is the `-User` parameter, that lets me choose a user, from which I know a loggin has happend on the target server (and therefor a windows profile exists). But this gets cumbersome as I would have to use e.g. `Get-WmiObject Win32_UserProfile -ComputerName MyComputer` first to retrieve a list of available user profiles and then choose one of them to execute `Get-GPResultantSetOfPolicy` later on...

The plain old `gpresult.exe` behaves exactly in the same odd way... I dont want/cant rdp into each server to generate a windows profile beforehand.

In my opinion there are two possibilites:

1. Use Scripting to generate a windows profile on each server and
   then get back to `Get-GPResultantSetOfPolicy`
2. RDP into each machine... (not feasable)

Questions:

- Any other possibility I am missing?
- How have others solved/worked around this issue?
- How can I generate/create a Windows Profile using powershell without rdp'ing?

Comment: I noticed you wrote that you tried GPRESULT, but did you also try the `/SCOPE COMPUTER` option with GPRESULT ?

Comment: Never checked with Powershell, but checkout my answer for the cmd command gpresult, it could be the same "feature": https://serverfault.com/a/883515/274412

Comment: Sorry, didn't read all the question until I finished to write my answer. So yes, we're on the same point: as far as I know, there's no other way except using an already existing profile. But about creating a remote profile, Enter-PSSession should work.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same situation and found a solution using gpresult.
Here are my additions to your code fragment:

```
$computers = (Get-ADComputer -Filter ... -SearchBase ...).Name 

foreach  ($computer in $computers)
{
    $LogPath = "\\Fileserver\share\RSOP_" + $computer + "_" + $(get-date).tostring('yyyy-MM-dd_hhmmss') + ".html"

    gpresult /S:"$computer" /H:"$logpath" 
}
```

This takes each computer in your search and creates a RSOP log using the computer name and date run.

Hope this helps those looking for bulk RSOP reports.